# Set the default audio level for any new program in Windows 7 to be lower than the speaker level?

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

As the title says. I keep my max "Speakers" volume at 100% to only adjust precisely audio levels in individual apps, but I would like of any new program (i.e. programs that have not been set a volume level already, which is remembered at the next program launch) to start not at 100% speaker level, which makes me shet my pants every time.

Is it possible to do in Windows 7?

Comment: The settings you're talking about are stored in the registry. I don't think there's a default value you can set for new programs, it only shows the list of existing programs, (and is rather cryptic as well.) The key is at: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore (yes, it has nothing to do with IE, but that's MS logic for you.)

Comment: That's really unfortunate. I might look into those settings anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Moab please re-read my question. :)